# Warning message purpose?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, warnings

While compiling a while loop without a body, I saw this message:

```
warning: suggest a space before ';' or explicit braces around empty body in
'while' statement
```

Why should I put a space? Is it to make it clearer that my loop isn't really doing anything?

Comment: That and that you didn't forget a "do".

Comment: I prefer the for statement for this.  The lack of one of the parts is like nails on a black board.  for(;;) is particularly powerful.

Comment: Be kind to your maintenance programmers: Document it when you do something that looks like a bug intentionally.

Comment: The question's title seems a bit general to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes -- the usual convention is to put it on a line by itself, something like this:

```
while (*d++ = *s++)
    ;
```

A few people prefer to use things like:

```
while (*d++ = *s++)
{
    /* intentionally empty */
}
```

Comment: `/* THIS SCOPE INTENTIONALLY LEFT BLANK */`

Answer (score 4):

> > Why should I put a space? Is it to make it clearer that my loop isn't really doing anything?

Yes, exactly that.

Many inexperienced programmers often put the `;` after a control flow statement like `for` or `while` because they assume that `;` goes at the end of every line, and not just at the end of statements and declarations. The warning is just suggesting to make it clearer that you understand that you've created an empty loop.

Answer (score 3):

A more obvious empty-body loop syntax is to use the `continue` statement:

```
while (condition_with_side_effects)
    continue;
```

That way no one will think you've accidentally added an extraneous `;`:

```
while (condition);    // bad style
```

Comment: Really liked the continue tip, I never thought about that, thanks 9 years in the future!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is just to show that you have not automatically placed a semicolon at the end of the line by mistake.